# How to find R, T and Q matrixes given K1, K2, D1, D2, P1, P2, R1 and R2 matrixes?

Tags: opencv

I downloaded a stereo database that contains the camera calibration parameters. I want to calculate the disparity map using the `cv::StereoBM` and reproject with `cv::reprojectImageTo3D`, but the database does not provide all stereo matrixes, so I need the **R**, **T**, and **Q** matrixes.

How I recover those matrixes? I have the **K1**, **K2**, **D1**, **D2**, **P1**, **P2**, **R1**, and **R2** matrixes.

*PS: If I use the `cv::stereoRectify` like:*

```
cv::stereoRectify(K1, D1, K2, D2, imageSize, R, T, R1, R2, P1, P2, Q,
                    cv::CALIB_ZERO_DISPARITY, 0, imageSize, 
                    &validRoi[0], &validRoi[1]);
```

I got the error

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (src.size == dst.size && src.channels() == dst.channels()) in cvConvertScale
error: (-215) src.size == dst.size && src.channels() == dst.channels() in function cvConvertScale
```

Comment: are the images rectified already? Can you provide the link to the darabase?

Comment: Link: http://rimlab.ce.unipr.it/Maris.php#MarisPortofino ([MARIS_Dataset_set1.tar.xz])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not quite sure about what all matrices mean. However you are not using stereoRectify in the correct way. [From the documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d9/d0c/group__calib3d.html#ga617b1685d4059c6040827800e72ad2b6) you see that R1, R2, P1, P2 are **output arrays**, R and T are **input arrays**.

If you wish to rectify your two images, I guess that you want to call initUndistortRectifyMap instead, which directly takes in R1, P1.
Assuming K1 is the camera matrix 1, D1 the distortion coefficients 1, you can call as:

```
Mat map11, map12;
initUndistortRectifyMap(K1, D1, R1, P1, img_size, CV_16SC2, map11, map12);
Mat img1r
remap(img1, img1r, map11, map12, INTER_LINEAR);
```

with img1r being your rectified image. This code is adapted from the sample in OpenCV: opencv/samples/cpp/stereo_match.cpp

For the matrix Q, which is needed for the function `reprojectImageTo3D`,  you might be interested by [this link](https://answers.opencv.org/question/187734/derivation-for-perspective-transformation-matrix-q/) or to look in the definition of stereoRectify in OpenCV code directly (opencv/modules/calib3d/src/calibration.cpp).

I hope this helps!

EDIT:

Actually, according to [this](https://answers.opencv.org/question/187734/derivation-for-perspective-transformation-matrix-q/), Q is just composed of cx, cy, tx and f. So I guess that you have them all: cx, cy, f are in K (camera matrix), and you can get tx using the right side P matrix which contain Tx * f. I think fx has to be used for f but you should probably check that.

Comment: I forgot that for the rectify the images it only needs the K1, D1, R1, P1 matrixes. Thanks. Now I only need to find the Q matrix. I took a look in the link that you provide, but I don't have the `f` and the `Tx` of the cameras. Is that some way to get it? The stereoRectify find the Q matrix, but it needs the R and T that I don't have

Comment: I fixed a mistake in the first link to the documentation. There are also some definition of the matrices there that should help you. I checked your matrices from the link you provided and in MOD_camera_info_right you have Tx * f = -1.40656900e+02. f should be also in the camera matrix K1 I guess. Check again the different links and the code, I'm sure you'll make sense out of it. I am sorry it would take too much time for me to dig into it myself.

Comment: Ok, Maybe you actually have everything. I edited the answer.

Comment: Thank you, I have some results with a Q matrix using `f` as `fx`. Disparity map of underwater images are very bad compared with air cameras